# How to handle partially embedded records?

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I've been having some trouble using Ember Data with my MongoDB back-end.
Let's say I have a User model, which contains a Media (the user picture). Sometimes `user.picture` is sent embed, sometimes the back-end only sends the Media ID.

How do I handle that with Ember Data? I haven't seen anything like this in the EmbeddedRecordsMixin, even if I think it's kinda easy to do (if it's an object, don't fetch it, if it's a string, fetch the corresponding object).

Comment: A decision here needs to be made. Should ember do the work to make the data consistent? Or should the backend to the work to send consistent data? You need to work out which one makes more sense to you and then present the code you have as a template for solving "one" of those problems. AKA. A: Browser client receives data it needs to make more requests to resolve. B: Server API realizes some data consists of references, therefore resolve them before sending to the client.

Answer (score 0):

With the EmbeddedRecordsMixin you can configure each per type adapter (or your app adapter) for the serialization needs to serialize `records` or `ids` But I do not think there is a way to sometimes use an `id` or sometimes use an embedded `record` in the payload. You would need to write your own custom adapter to handle that use case.